# Creating a plain text file on local machine with php, with path

Tags: php

I just started programming on php. I need my script to open or create `(fopen())` a plain text file at the end of the script. I am using Ubuntu.

The book I am following suggests,

```
@ $fp = fopen(“$DOCUMENT_ROOT/../orders/orders.txt”, 'ab');
```

but I am programming on my local machine, so I tried the script to create “orders.txt” on an alternative path:

```
'/opt/lampp/htdocs/orders/orders.txt'
```

This doesn't seem to work, although some time ago I think I was able to make it work on Windows,

I am only some weeks into this,

Thank you,

S.

Comment: How does it fail?  Did you check the logs for errors/warnings?  Does the PHP user context have write permission to that path?

Comment: Never use @ to hide your errors. It is bad practice to hide errors via @. In development mode, You should ON your error reporting.

Comment: Error handling and detection is your friend.  Like Ravi Hirani says, loose the "@".  Follow Rahul Dhande's example, and look at the PHP fopen link he cites.  And use either "a" or "w" - but there's probably no need for "ab".

Comment: Thank you guys, great help. Got rid of the @ and it turned out it was a permissions issue. Being used to Windows, I never thought about permissions.

Answer (score 6):

Refer [fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) manual:-

Try this code:-

```
<?php
    $myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
    $txt = "John Doe\n";
    fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    $txt = "Jane Doe\n";
    fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    fclose($myfile);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Rahul Dhande's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35547379/4198099) is perfect.

Here is another alternative. You can also use

**[file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)** — Write a string to a file

**[file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)** — Reads entire file into a string

```
$file = 'people.txt';
// Open the file to get existing content
$current = file_get_contents($file);
// Append a new person to the file
$current .= "John Smith\n";
// Write the contents back to the file
file_put_contents($file, $current);
```

Hope it will help you :)